# Sort based on multiple things in C++

Tags: c++

```
struct Record
{
    char Surname[20];
    char Initial;
    unsigned short int Gender; //0 = male | 1 = female
    unsigned short int Age;
};
Record X[100];
```

How can I use Quicksort to sort the values into increasing age, with females before males and surnames in alphabetical order? I've got a:

```
bool CompareData(const int& A, const int& B)
{
    return Records[A].Age < Records[B].Age; //this sorts by age atm
}
```

Comment: does it have to be quicksort?

Comment: Well I have implemented quicksort, however I'm not sure how to alert the CompareData() to sort correctly.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
bool CompareData(const int& A, const int& B)
{
    return (Records[A].Age < Records[B].Age) ||
           ((Records[A].Age == Records[B].Age) && (Records[A].Gender > Records[B].Gender)) || 
           ((Records[A].Age == Records[B].Age) && (Records[A].Gender == Records[B].Gender) &&
              (strcmp(Records[A].Surname, Records[B].Surname) < 0));
}
```

This compares first by age and returns true if A should appear before B based on age.

If ages are equal, it then compares by gender, and returns true if A should appear before B based on gender (A is female and B is male).

If ages are equal and genders are equal, it then compares by surname (using `strcmp`, although if you had used `std::string` instead of a char array, you could have just used `<`), and returns true if A should appear before B alphabetically by surname.

Answer (score 64):

the general pattern is:

```
bool CompareData(const T& a, const T& b) 
{ 
   if (a.PrimaryCondition < b.PrimaryCondition) return true;
   if (b.PrimaryCondition < a.PrimaryCondition) return false;

   // a=b for primary condition, go to secondary
   if (a.SecondaryCondition < b.SecondaryCondition) return true;
   if (b.SecondaryCondition < a.SecondaryCondition) return false;

   // ...

   return false;
}
```

where `<` indicates the "less than" in the desired sort order, you might need to use custom comparison operators for that (e.g. `strcmp` for strings,or reverse the `<` if you want to order descending)   (thanks Harry for pointing this out)

I've used `<` on all conditions, since that's sometimes the only comparison operation available, e.g. when you have to use an unknown data type's comparison predicate.

[edit] Note: the last line `return false` handles the case where `a`and `b`are considered equal for the comparator.

Imagine `a.PrimaryCondition==b.PrimaryCondition` and `a.SecondaryCondition==b.SecondaryCondition` - in this case, none of the previous conditions returns any value.

Comment: But be aware that the logical `<` relation may not always map to the `<` operator. For example, comparing the genders by `<` will be backwards, since females should appear before males, and the female value is larger, so for gender it must be `>`. And because the surnames are C-strings, the `<` operator applied to the surname field would not give a lexicographic ordering. Something like `strcmp` must be used instead.

Comment: Why can't you just `return a.primary < b.primary` and `return a.secondary < b.secondary`?

Comment: @ElanHickler: because `.secondary` must be evaluated iff `a.primary==b.primary`. if `a.primary > b.primary`, the result is false, irrespective of the values of `.secondary`.

Comment: @peterchen What does that `false` in the end uphold? I tried `true` in order to maintain some stability in the sort, but that messed up the results.

Comment: @gustafbstrom: It handles the case that `a` and `b` are equal in the sense of the comparison operator. (so it should indeed be `false`!) --- I'll update the answer

Comment: @peterchen OK, but I fail to see _why_ it's false -- if coming to that point, aren't they considered all equal such that changing the order should _not_ matter?

Comment: @gustafbstrom: The predicate for sorts needs to return `true` if and only if `a < b`, i.e. `false` for `a==b`.  For details, see here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare  --- Returning `true`here *will* mess up your results. Just consider: the test for equality 
 is `!(a<b) && !(b<a)`. Your `return true` will fail that test.

Comment: Also: even if you can assert that all your elements are unique (and so logically could not be equal) I've still observed that `a` and `b` could refer to the same object (at least, there seems no requirement to the contrary), so it's still essential you return `false` for the same reason @peterchen makes above.

Answer (score 21):

the other option to an all singing all dancing comparator is to make sure your sort is a stable sort (quick sort isn't necessarily stable) and sort multiple times with different comparators each time.

e.g.

```
bool CompareAge (const record& l, const record& r)
{
  return l.age < r.age;
}

bool CompareGender (const record& l, const record& r)
{
  return l.gender < r.gender;
}

std::stable_sort(X, X+100, &CompareGender);
std::stable_sort(X, X+100, &CompareAge);
```

this will be potentially slightly slower but allow you more flexibility with the order of sorts

Comment: But Quicksort is *not* stable. (After your edit) As I said, `std::sort` is not stable; you should use `std::stable_sort` instead.

Comment: it can be. depends on the implementation

Comment: Answer depending on implementation is not a good answer at all. ;)

Comment: std::sort is also not guaranteed to be stable -> changed to stable_sort

Comment: technically quick sort can be stable depending on how you pick the pivot, its just the stable implementations aren't usually used as they are slower. as the OP was implementing their own quick sort i thought it best not to presume

Comment: It should be noted that the sorts are in reverse priority. Gender is sorted first, then Age, so that Age is the most significant sort key. To answer the OP, there should be a `std::stable_sort(X,X+100,&CompareSurname)` before `...CompareGender...`

Answer (score 16):

The simple C++ solution is

```
struct Record {
    std::string Surname;
    char Initial;
    unsigned short int Gender; //0 = male | 1 = female
    unsigned short int Age;

    operator<(Record const& rhs) const {
        return std::tie(Gender, Age, Surname) < std::tie(rhs.Gender, rhs.Age, rhs.Surname);
};
```

However, `std::tie` sorts directly on the field values. This means you can't use `char[20]` and males will sort first. A simple variation solves this:

```
struct Record {
    char Surname[20];
    char Initial;
    unsigned short int Gender; //0 = male | 1 = female
    unsigned short int Age;

    operator<(Record const& rhs) const {
        return std::make_tuple(~Gender, Age, std::string(Surname)) <
               std::make_tuple(~rhs.Gender, rhs.Age, std::string(rhs.Surname));
};
```

With `make_tuple` we can pass expressions.

Comment: You can also mix the approaches to avoid copies where possible, storing off converted values to function local variables first, then returning the result of `std::tie`, using the existing members when possible, and the converted values otherwise. Or reversing it, use `std::make_tuple`, but wrap unmodified arguments in `std::ref`/`std::cref` to make the resulting `tuple` contain a reference rather than a copy of the value. In this case, no real need (since only one member is non-value type, and it must be converted to `string` [or on C++17, `string_view`] anyway), but useful in other cases.

Comment: You can also use `std::forward_as_tuple` if you want to mix references and expressions.

Answer (score 5):

It's better to implement comparator like this:

```
bool CompareRecords(const Record& a, const Record& b)
{
    if (a.Age < b.Age)
        return true;
    else if (a.Age > b.Age)
        return false;

    if (a.Gender < b.Gender)
        return true;
    else if (a.Gender > b.Gender)
        return false;

    if (strcmp(a.Surname, b.Surname) < 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

This allows you to easy use of `std::sort` algorithm. Sorting itself will look like this:

```
std::sort(X, X + 100, &CompareRecords);
```

#### EDIT

You may even want to implement `operator <` for this structure -- in that case you can normally compare two objects of `Record` structure with operator `<`. And then you don't need to add the third parameter to `std::sort`. And well, with that and implemented `operator ==` you can make all possible comparizons. :)

Comment: So std::sort is better than using my own Quicksort?

Comment: Yes, `std::sort` is better solution -- as long as you don't want to lern how to implement Quicksort itself. But in that case sorting structures like that is not a good idea. ;)

Comment: @Johnny `std::sort` is better than your own quicksort mainly because you don't have to write it. Unless the point of what you're programming is to teach yourself sorting algorithms, you should generally use what already exists.

Comment: But my CompareData returns bool

Comment: @Johnny The problem with your function, with respect to `std::sort` isn't that it doesn't return `bool`, it's that it doesn't take `const Record&` as arguments. The `std::sort` function needs to give its comparator actual record structures to compare, not indexes into the records array like your function takes right now.

Comment: ah ok, so I need a function that compares elements? Not sorting an array of Indexes?